# Is /**/ comment preferred than //?

Tags: c, coding-style, comments

A year ago, I started to experiment with C, I saw a comment `//` that explained the stdio.h header. Today, deciding to read K&R C (It is the most recommended book to read according stackoverflow posts) I keep seeing this `/* comment */` comment and never saw the `//` comment. Is there a difference between the two? (Do they have a different purpose?) Is there a coding style about this?

Comment: C89 didn’t support line comments, for one.

Comment: Same thing but /**/ is easier when trying to comment multiple lines of code at once. I personally use both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The K&R C book (second edition) describes ANSI C (also known as C89). In this version `//`-comments weren't allowed in C, but they are in (ISO) C99. They were inherited from C++.

The difference between the two is that:

- `//`-comments are *line-comments* meaning that they extend from the point where the `//` start until the next new-line.
- `/* */`-comments are block comments meaning that they start at `/*` and end at `*/`. They can span multiple lines and they can start and end in the same line with code surrounding it, such as:

  ```
  printf("%s\n", /* I wonder if this could be done simpler */ "Hello world!");
  ```

  in this case a line-comment would yield:

  ```
  printf("%s\n", // I wonder if this could be done simpler "Hello world!");
  ```

  which would be a syntax error, unless the `printf` statement is continued on the next line.

Comment: +1 for describing old and new C standard, but you should also mention about the difference/similarity ( If any ) between two.

Comment: @Kninnug Thank you for the clarification. I never knew it wasn't supported. This answer is the best for me since you described the comments and cite out the differences.

Comment: Now it is much better. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight difference. If you want to comment whole blocks (multiple lines) of code with '//' you must put a '//' at the beginning of each line. In addition, the '//' comments out everything on the line after that sequence.

```
// This
// is
// a
// block
// comment
```

The '/* .. */' version has a definite beginning and end, so you can use one sequence to comment however much (or little) you desire.

While this is not always the best idea (it can get confusing to try and read), it's possible to comment out only portions of a line with the '/* .. */' version.

```
for(i = 0; i < /* TEST_VAL */ NOT_TEST_VAL; ++i)
```

You can't do that with //

```
for(i = 0; i < // TEST_VAL NOT_TEST_VAL; ++i)
```

Malformed expression much?

Also, like others have noted, you cannot use the '//' expression in any C89 restricted code.

Answer (score 0):

The original C specs didn't include // style comments, this was AFAIK only officially introduced with C++. Basically all current compilers support it, though, also in C only mode. For short single line comments, it is therefore preferred, as it is easier to type. Project specific coding guidelines will usualy say which to use where.

Answer (score 0):

I use both.  One thing to consider when you are deciding on a comment type:

If you use the `/* ... */` style to comment out a small patch of text, say within a function, and later want to comment out the entire function, you will run into problems if you aren't careful.  For example:

```
/*
void my_function() {
    ...
    some_line_of_code(); /* your old comment */
    ...
}
*/
```

The compiler will interpret the closing `*/` of the old comment as the end of the comment block, which is not what you want.  If you use the `//` style for line comments this is a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

While they weren't allowed in c89, they are allowed now. The main difference between the two is the number of lines your comment needs. But generally:

```
int x = 0 // This comment can be used for quick descriptions.
/*
 * This kind of comment should be used for multiple lines
 * that take more than 3 lines.
 */
```

In the end, it all depends what you prefer, but this is general convention that I've seen on how to use each comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**/
```

Would probably be better for use when writing multi lines of comments, as such:

```
System.out.println("Hello, world!");
/* Basic hello world statement
yada yada yada
Goodbye */
```

"//" styled comments would probably serve the purpose of writing single line comments, as shown:

```
// This instance declares a private variable
```

Comment: Your answer appears to be about Java, this question is about C (though the comment-syntax is in this case exactly the same as Java inherited this syntax from C)

Comment: @Kninnug The syntax is the same as C as it is in Java.